# what is the best way to store a user filtered query params in a database table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, query-string, database-schema

I have an ASP.NET MVC website. In my backend I have a table called `People` with the following columns:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Age
4. Location
5. ... (a number of other cols)

I have a generic web page that uses model binding to query this data.  Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult GetData(FilterParams filterParams)
{
      return View(_dataAccess.Retrieve(filterParams.Name, filterParams.Age, filterParams.location, . . .)
}
```

which maps onto something like this:

```
 http://www.mysite.com/MyController/GetData?Name=Bill .. .
```

The dataAccess layer simply checks each parameter to see if its populated to add to the db where clause.  This works great.

I now want to be able to store a user's filtered queries and I am trying to figure out the best way to store a specific filter.  As some of the filters only have one param in the queryString while others have 10+ fields in the filter I can't figure out the most elegant way to storing this query "filter info" into my database.

Options I can think of are:

1. Have a complete replicate of the table (with some extra cols) but call it PeopleFilterQueries and populate in each record a FilterName and put the value of the filter in each of field (Name, etc)
2. Store a table with just FilterName and a string where I store the actual querystring Name=Bill&Location=NewYork.  This way I won't have to keep adding new columns if the filters change or grow.

What is the best practice for this situation?

Comment: What is the purpose of the filter *data*? I would *not* recommend storing the "actual query string" but, **if and only if it is an opaque data-type** (wrt the model), then I would store an encoded value that nicely maps to a Domain Object (and supports trivial serialization). If it is an opaque type -- or not -- depends upon your requirements.

Comment: Do you ever need to query this data? The answer to that will guide you to use serialization or create a filter query table + key/value table.

Comment: Which is the reason for storing it in the database? is for reporting? Trending? Remembering the last filters? How often this filter information will be used?

Comment: @ivowiblo - its to allow users to see recent filters ..  (of course they could just use bookmarks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the purpose is to save a list of recently used filters, I would serialise the complete FilterParams object into an XML field/column after the model binding has occurred. By saving it into a XML field you're also giving yourself the flexibility to use XQuery and DML should the need arise at a later date for more performance focused querying of the information.

```
    public ActionResult GetData(FilterParams filterParams)
    {
          // Peform action to get the information from your data access layer here
          var someData = _dataAccess.Retrieve(filterParams.Name, filterParams.Age, filterParams.location, . . .);

          // Save the search that was used to retrieve later here
          _dataAccess.SaveFilter(filterParams);
          return View(someData);
    }
```

And then in your DataAccess Class you'll want to have two Methods, one for saving and one for retrieving the filters:

```
public void SaveFilter(FilterParams filterParams){
    var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FilterParams));
    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
           {
              // serialise to the stream
              ser.Serialize(stream, filterParams);
           }
  //Add new database entry here, with a serialised string created from the FilterParams obj
  someDBClass.SaveFilterToDB(stream.ToString());
}
```

Then when you want to retrieve a saved filter, perhaps by Id:

```
public FilterParams GetFilter(int filterId){

      //Get the XML blob from your database as a string
      string filter = someDBClass.GetFilterAsString(filterId);

      var ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FilterParams));

      using (var sr = new StringReader(filterParams))
      {
          return (FilterParams)ser.Deserialize(sr);
      }
}
```

Remember that your FilterParams class must have a default (i.e. parameterless) constructor, and you can use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute to prevent properties from being serialised into the database should you wish.

```
public class FilterParams{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Age {get;set;}

   [XmlIgnore]
   public string PropertyYouDontWantToSerialise {get;set;}
}
```

Note: The SaveFilter returns Void and there is no error handling for brevity.

Comment: This is what I do for saving objects that will NEVER need to be reported or queried.  This option will make it difficult to see how many users have a saved query with name=bob.  And by "difficult" i just mean that it will take a lot of time to run the query.  No indexes, etc.

Comment: @DMoses Well performance wasn't directly part of the OP and I don't think you can just say something will take "a lot of time to run a query" (and probably downvote) without backing it up with some metrics. Running a `SELECT XmlField.value('(//SomePropertyName)[1]', 'PropertyType') as SomePropertyName FROM [TableName]` on a table with an XML field containing 13 props over 200k rows returns the value parsed from the XML in under 2 seconds - not lightning I agree, but for the flexibility you get with saving objects, I think the payoff is worth it in some cases.

Comment: @tristan I upvoted and thought your answer was good.  I just wanted the OP to realize there was a performance tradeoff.

Comment: @DMoses Oh, thank you - must have been some other little swine that down voted me without leaving feedback then. Sorry for the accusation.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing the querystring, I would serialize the `FilterParams` object as JSON/XML and store the result in your database.

Here's a JSON Serializer I regularly use:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace Fabrik.Abstractions.Serialization
{
    public class JsonSerializer : ISerializer<string>
    {
        public string Serialize<TObject>(TObject @object) {
            var dc = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TObject));
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                dc.WriteObject(ms, @object);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        public TObject Deserialize<TObject>(string serialized) {
            var dc = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TObject));
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized)))
            {
                return (TObject)dc.ReadObject(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then deserialize the object and pass it your data access code as per your example above.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention about exact purpose of storing the filter.

If you insist to save filter into a database table, I would have following structure of the table.

- FilterId
- Field
- FieldValue

An example table might be

```
FilterId Field    FieldValue
1        Name     Tom
1        Age      24
1        Location IL       
3        Name     Mike
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is much more simple than you are making it:

*Essentially you should store the raw query in its own table and relate it to your People table. Don't bother storing individual filter options.*

**Decide on a value to store (2 options)**

1. *Store the URL Query String*

   This id be beneficial if you like open API-style apps, and want something you can pass nicely back and forth from the client to the server and re-use without transformation.
2. *Serialize the Filter object as a string*

   This is a really nice approach if your purpose for storing these filters remains entirely server side, and you would like to keep the data closer to a class object.

**Relate your `People` table to your `Query Filters Table`:**

The best strategy here depends on what your intention and performance needs are. Some suggestions below:

- *Simple filtering (ex. 2-3 filters, 3-4 options each)*

  Use `Many-To-Many` because the number of combinations suggests that the same filter combos will be used lots of times by lots of people.
- *Complex filtering*

  Use `One-To-Many` as there are so many possible individual queries, it less likely they are to be reused often enough to make the extra-normalization and performance hit worth your while.

There are certainly other options but they would depend on more detailed nuances of your application. The suggestions above would work nicely if you are say, trying to keep track of "recent queries" for a user, or "user favorite" filtering options...

**Personal opinion**
Without knowing much more about your app, I would say (1) store the query string, and (2) use OTM related tables... if and when your app shows a need for further performance profiling or issues with refactoring filter params, then come back... but chances are, it wont.

GL.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to save the "Filter" is to have some kind of json text string with each of the "columns names"

So you will have something in the db like

**Table Filters**

*FilterId = 5 ; FilterParams = {'age' : '>18' , ...*

Json will provide a lot of capabilities, like the use of age as an array to have more than one filter to the same "column", etc.

Also json is some kind of standard, so you can use this "filters" with other db some day or to just "display" the filter or edit it in a web form. If you save the Query you will be attached to it.

Well, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a nosql/object database such as [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) is out of the question, I would definitely go with option 1. Sooner or later you'll find the following requirements or others coming up:

1. Allow people to save their filters, label, tag, search and share them via bookmarks, tweets or whatever.
2. Change what a parameter means or what it does, which will require you to version your filters for backward compatibility.
3. Provide auto-complete functions over filters, possibly using a user's filter history to inform the auto-complete.

The above will be somewhat harder to satisfy if you do any kind of binary/string serialization where you'll need to parse the result and then process them.

If you *can* use a NoSql DB, then you'll get all the benefits of a sql store plus be able to model the 'arbitrary number of key/value pairs' very well.

Answer (score 0):

Have thought about using Profiles. This is a build in mechanism to store user specific info. From your description of your problem its seems a fit.

[Profiles In ASP.NET 2.0](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx)

I have to admit that M$ implementation is a bit dated but there is essentially nothing wrong with the approach. If you wanted to roll your own, there's quite a bit of good thinking in their API.

Comment: Profiles in ASP.NET are well suited to very basic user profile information, however the default implementation is difficult to perform a simple query upon.  Take a look at how it stores the profile data in the database, http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/03/04/how-asp-net-profile-properties-are-serialized-in-the-database-using-sql-profile-provider.aspx